# Python: is it possible to modify the writeability of built-in function attributes?

Tags: python, attributes, namespaces, introspection

Let's say I want to change `print`'s name, so that I'd call it via `pr('string')` (and free up `print`).

```
print.__setattr__('__name__', 'pr')
```

gives

```
AttributeError: attribute '__name__' of 'builtin_function_or_method' objects is not writable
```

Is it possible to modify this writeability?

Edit:

I'm aware that function pointers can be changed at will, like

```
pr = print
```

However, I'm interested in the possiblity of modifying the attribute.

There's no real context here, I'd like to understand more about the fundamental properties. Off the top of my head, though, one might imagine something like translating the namespace as an i18n effort:

```
builtin_functions = [name for name, obj in vars(builtins).items() 
                      if isinstance(obj, types.BuiltinFunctionType)]
for f in builtin_functions: 
    f.__setattr__('__name__', i18n_function(__getattribute__('__name__')))
```

Comment: I'm just wondering what would be the context for why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could assign `print` to a different variable:

```
def whatever(text: str):
    pass

pr = print
print = whatever

pr("printing")
print("won't be printed")
```

just outputs `printing`.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't quite answer the question. I'll improve the wording to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

There are two competing notions of "name" here. The important one is the Python definition of a name, which is an identifier in a particular scope that refers to a value. Here, `print` is a name in the built-in scope that refers to a value of type `builtin_function_or_method`.

The other one is the `__name__` attribute of the `builtin_function_or_method`. It plays *no* role in name lookup; changing the `__name__` attribute has no effect on how you refer to something. Here's an example using a user-defined method whose `__name__` attribute you *can* change:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> foo.__name__ = 'bar'
>>> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Comment: Oooh, that's very helpful, thank you! Can you elaborate on how to do what I was looking for, ie. to actually change `foo` to `bar` as per your example?

Comment: You already know that: `bar = foo`. I'm not sure what else you are looking for. The name used to refer to a function is not a property of the function itself.

Comment: Oh, I see... so, if I were to actually implement the example I came up with, I'd actually have to do something like `exec('''new function definitions''', globals())`?

Comment: And, out of curiosity - even though `__name__` seems pretty irrelevant after your explanation - is there a way to make it modifiable after all?